# xslt - check that document exists

Tags: xml, xslt

In XSL I am accessing an XML file which contains a config variable which is used in the stylesheet using the document function.

```
<xsl:variable name="files" select="document(concat('../../../', utils:Replace(./@src, '/groceries/MarketingContent/', 'MarketingContent/'), '.xml'))/Files" />

<xsl:call-template name="script">
                    <xsl:with-param name="src" select="concat('/groceries/',$files/@outputPath,'/', utils:Replace($files/File/@name, '.js', concat('.', $files/@hashKey, '.js')))"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
```

The problem is if this xml document does not exists I get an error, rendering the website unuable.

I am using version 1.0, is there a way to check that a file exists so as to deal with this issue gracefully??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of doing this in XSLT 1.0 without processor-specific extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there is no standard way to do this in XSLT 1.0. But if you tell us what XSLT processor you are using, there may be extensions you can use that are specific to the processor.

E.g. see

- [here](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200506/msg00400.html), and
- [here](http://xsl.markmail.org/thread/zy5q5xbumi2lwekl)